# Are Math humour posts allowed?

Tags: discussion

Can we see/send some math humour posts, Please? I know there are math joke sites, but I find some comments from poeple here extreemly funy. It would be good to hear jokes that require some topology/calculus/complex-analysis/.. etc.

Maybe even some type of favorite jokes for different fields? having tags like :
humour ,topology

humour ,calculus

humour ,group-theorry

Just to be able to compare the popularity of math jokes cross the disciplines.

Thank you all

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would strongly prefer that this not happen. This is exactly what chat is for, and having it spill onto the main site would more or less be spam (in the sense that it detracts from the main purpose of the site, which is asking and answering mathematical questions).

Comment: The funny thing is I had to ask this after reading your quotation of immortal words of Lindsy Lohan! wanted more of similar posts. tx

Comment: Comments are comments; I assumed you were referring to questions and answers, which I would like to keep relatively on-topic.

Comment: It was a good comment, very enetertaing and it still makes me laugh, and it was to the point with humour.

Comment: I made a joke as an answer, and it got deleted pretty quickly. Does this mean it would have been ok as a comment? I would try posting it as a comment, but I reckon that's pretty certain to raise the ire of the people who deleted the answer... (And it was deleted because it wasn't a good answer, not because it was profane, or anything like that)

Answer (score 14):

This rarely ends well in my experience.

There are some fun-ish on topic questions, but I do not feel the *goal* of a question should ever be pure idle amusement.